# Create button to call specific number - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I know this question has been answered a couple of times on here but I am having a slightly bigger issue with the problem as Android Studio is giving me errors I have not come across before (I am new at android programming).

Inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` I have the following code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Inside the java class I have the following code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

My problem is that the `startActivity(callIntent);` is giving me the following error:

[image]

Which then lead Android Studio to add this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Android studio then gave one last error which was:

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, could someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `this` in your situation, you are reffering to `View.OnClickListener` (because `onClick()` it's overriden method inner class). You need to add your Activity class name before it (example below for `MainActivity`).

Change

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
```

to

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
```